# Non static fields in unit test don't update on second and further test run

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, mstest, microsoft-fakes

I encountered this weird situation and do not see explanation.

```
[TestClass]
public class DbHelpersTests
{
    int addCalls;
    int commitCalls;
    int updateCalls;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        StubICustomerRepository stubRepo = new StubICustomerRepository()
        {
            AddCustomerModelBoolean = (model, autoSave) => 
            {
                addCalls++;
                return true;
            },

            Commit = () => 
            {
                commitCalls++;
                return true;
            }
        };

        StubIOrderRepository orderRepo = new StubIOrderRepository()
        {
            AddOrderBoolean = (order, save) => 
            {
                addCalls++;
                return true;
            },

            UpdateOrderBoolean = (order, save) =>
            {
                updateCalls++;
                return true;
            }
        };
        ...
    }

    [TestCleanup]
    public void CleanUp()
    {
        addCalls = 0;
        commitCalls = 0;
        updateCalls = 0;
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void AddMultipleCustomers()
    {
        ...
        List<Customer> data = PrepareData(10);
        // commit after each 2 customers
        DbHelpers.InsertAllCustomers(data, 2);

        Assert.AreEqual(10, addCalls);
        Assert.AreEqual(5, commitCalls);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void AddSingleOrder()
    {
        ...
        DbHelpers.InsertOrder(new Order());

        Assert.AreEqual(1, addCalls);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void UpdateSingleOrder()
    {
        ...
        DbHelpers.UpdateOrder(new Order());

        Assert.AreEqual(1, updateCalls);
    }
}
```

When I run my tests, the first one `AddMultipleCustomers` passes and later two don't. They fail because `addCalls` and `updateCalls` fields are both 0.

When I run only `AddSingleOrder` test it passes. Same with `UpdateSingleOrder`.

Why, when running all tests, in second and following test runs, fields `addCalls` and `updateCalls` are not updated anymore?

When I changed the declaration of fields to `static int addCalls;`, all tests passed. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Have you stepped through it in the debugger?  I figure DbHelpers is static methods.  Without having more of the code... since TestInitialized is called every test, new stubs are generated, but maybe the static methods are still referencing the first stubs and the first instances of the class variables (they get recreated after each run).  So the second and third runs are referencing new versions of the fields that are set to 0 and the Stubs are incrementing the first version.  You should be able to use the debugger to check (just remove the explicit set to 0 in the cleanup method).